# Equivalent of setState callback with React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a modal with a list of answers.
I can either click an answer to select it, then click a button to confirm my choice.
Or I can double-click an answer to select it and confirm.

I'm having trouble properly handling the double-click case.

With React class components, I would have used `setState()`'s callback like this:

```
setState({selectedAnswer: answer}, confirm)
```

But right now, I only figured out the following:

```
const MyModal = ({hide, setAnwser}) => {
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState(null);
  const [isSelectionDone, setIsSelectionDone] = useState(false);

  const confirm = () => {
    if (!selectedAnswer) {
      return;
    }

    setAnwser(selectedAnswer);
    hide();
  };

  const handleAnswerOnClick = (answer) => {
    setSelectedAnswer(answer);
  };

  const handleAnswerOnDoubleClick = (answer) => {
    setSelectedAnswer(answer);
    setIsSelectionDone(true);
  };

  useEffect(confirm, [isSelectionDone]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{answers.map((answer) => <MyAnswer
        isSelected={answer.id === selectedAnswer?.id}
        key={answer.id}
        answer={answer}
        onClick={handleAnswerOnClick}
        onDoubleClick={handleAnswerOnDoubleClick}/>)}</div>
      <button onClick={confirm}>Confirm</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I strongly suspect that there's a nicer/better way of doing it.

Maybe a simple:

```
const MyModal = ({hide, setAnwser}) => {
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState(null);

  const confirm = () => {
    if (!selectedAnswer) {
      return;
    }

    setAnwser(selectedAnswer);
    hide();
  };

  const handleAnswerOnClick = (answer) => {
    setSelectedAnswer(answer);
  };

  const handleAnswerOnDoubleClick = (answer) => {
    setAnwser(answer);
    hide();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{answers.map((answer) => <MyAnswer
        isSelected={answer.id === selectedAnswer?.id}
        key={answer.id}
        answer={answer}
        onClick={handleAnswerOnClick}
        onDoubleClick={handleAnswerOnDoubleClick}/>)}</div>
      <button onClick={confirm}>Confirm</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which way is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no similar set state in hooks (which fires callback after state is set).
But, you could apply following refactor:

```
 const confirm = (sAnswer = selectedAnswer) => {
    if (!sAnswer) {
      return;
    }

    setAnwser(sAnswer);
    hide();
  };
```

And then

```
 const handleAnswerOnDoubleClick = (answer) => {
    setSelectedAnswer(answer);
    confirm(answer);
  };
```

Comment: Thansk for the idea. I'll do that.
Although I think I'll skip `setSelectedAnswer(answer);` which won't be of any use since the modal will be closed by `confirm()`.